# Create a plist file every time a new view controller file is created in a Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode

I am wondering how it might be possible to create a plist file every time a new view controller file is created in a Xcode project. This would be an automated process that would be used in this case.

Comment: Why do you want to do so? What is the function of the `plist`?

Comment: Sorry, the plist will have the same name as the view controller and hold a property of the date the view controller was created and possibly other properties. @Raptor

Comment: The two lowest friction ways that I can think of are making a script that runs during the build process that checks for new view controller files and creates the plist or a hook connected to your source control. Neither will give you the file at the *exact* time the VC was created, but the first may get you pretty close.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom template.

Within a new folder ( e.g.: YourTemplateName.xctemplate) you add the files.

```
___FILEBASENAME___ViewController.swift // the viewcontroller you want to create
___FILEBASENAME___.plist // the plist you want to create
TemplateIcon.png // icon within xcode 
TemplateIcon@2x.png // icon within xcode 
TemplateInfo.plist //  plist to customize your template and the files you want to create
```

[image]

Check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/26582967-xcode-project-and-file-templates) for more informations about your possibilities.

In the end you need to copy your template folder to

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Other
```

and restart Xcode.

Now when you add a new File and scroll to the `Other` section you see your custom Template. If you choose this it creates a viewcontroller and a plist.

**EDIT:**

You need to customize the TemplateInfo.plist entries.

e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>DefaultCompletionName</key>
    <string>ViewController</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>ViewController+plist</string>
    <key>Kind</key>
    <string>Xcode.IDEKit.TextSubstitutionFileTemplateKind</string>
    <key>Options</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>The name of the module to create</string>
            <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>moduleName</string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>New module Name:</string>
            <key>NotPersisted</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Required</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>text</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>SortOrder</key>
    <string>9</string>
    <key>Summary</key>
    <string>ViewController+plist</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string></string>
</dict>
</plist
```

[image]

Your own plist needs default entries as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<!--
  

   Copyright (c) 2022 ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
-->
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

Your controller could look like:

```
//
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PROJECTNAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  ___COPYRIGHT___
//

import UIKit 

final class ___VARIABLE_moduleName___ : ViewController {
    // your default viewcontroller code which should always be added on creation 
}
```

The Custom template is ONLY created if you add it via
File -> New -> File -> THE_NAME_YOU_GAVE_YOUR_XCTEMPLATE_FOLDER

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understood what you are after as I tried and the result was not as expected. A swift file was created that looks exactly how you had stated above.
`___FILEBASENAME___ViewController.swift // the viewcontroller you want to create
___FILEBASENAME___.plist // the plist you want to create
TemplateIcon.png // icon within xcode 
TemplateIcon@2x.png // icon within xcode 
TemplateInfo.plist //  plist to customize your template and the files you want to create`

Comment: No additional plist or view controller file is created.